# Can flying creatures fly forever without needing to land to regain stamina?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, flight

There are many creatures that can fly in DnD.  However, none of the templates show any need to land and regen stamina after flying for so long. Is that actually a thing in DnD, or can flying creatures like an owl, an imp etc. fly forever without needing to land?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [overland movement rules](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/movement.htm#overlandMovement) apply to flying as well as to land movement, so it is possible to fatigue yourself by flying too much. There are not any rules for flying being *more* tiring than walking, however. Also, there’s nothing about hovering (or treading water, for that matter) causing fatigue; all the rules for getting tired while moving focus on *movement* so if you don’t change position they don’t (obviously) apply.

A few specific creatures have rules limiting their flight to certain durations after which they’re required to land. This is relatively rare, however, and almost entirely found on player-focused material since the game rarely has monsters “on screen” long enough for it to be relevant.

Comment: It might be worth noting that there are real creatures that fly for very long periods such as albatross, so it is not unreasonable for creatures to be flying indefinitely in a fantasy setting such as d&d.